# My JavaScript object has a length field which I didn't assign

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have a rather strange problem which I haven't been able to find a solution to. It might be because no one has had this issue, or it could be the fact that I'm rather lost on what to Google.

Here's what's going on. I'm building a Rock-Paper-Scissors machine learning demo, and I have two JavaScript objects which are important to the script. Those two objects are the `winners` (an object which stores what beats what), and `history` (keeps track of all the plays).

At the very top of my script, I make both of those objects, as such:

```
var winners = {

}

var history = {

}
```

Now I'm getting to the problem. I have the rest of the code done, but it is irrelevant, because when I comment it out, and since I'm using p5.js, I have a preload function where I simply print out both objects.

```
function preload(){
    console.log(winners);
    console.log(history);
}
```

Then I go into Chrome and run the html which uses the script, open the console. I should see:

```
Object {}
Object {}
```

But NOPE!

```
Object {}
History {length: 1, scrollRestoration: "auto", state: null}
```

The winners object is just an empty object, but my history object has a length attribute as well as some other stuff. All of my other code is commented out, I promise.

Why does my history object have the stuff in it and how can I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: Daneel, I've edited some of your questions as you are using the words "Java", "JavaScript" and "JSON" as interchangeable synonyms, which they aren't. Each represents a different technology and it never hurts to be precise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser contains a `window.history` object, which is what you are seeing in the console log. See more information about this object here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history

To circumvent this problem, use a slightly different name for your history object.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!! I'm accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Funny: Firefox warns about this in the console (*TypeError: setting a property that has only a getter*) but Chrome pretends it accepts the change to then discard it.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a built-in object called `history` in the browser.

You can read more about it in:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_history.asp